# How do I assert that a model has a readable/writable attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, metaprogramming, shoulda

In one of my model's I'm using some meta programming to dynamically define some methods. I'd like to test this; thus, I need a compact way to assert my model has a readable/writable attribute with a certain name. Ideas?

I'm using shoulda for unit testing if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you might be able to use
should_have_instance_methods or should_have_class_methods shoulda macros - I have not tried for this use case and they might rely on your object having super class of ActiveRecord::Base

what about respond_to?

```
o = some_dynamic_object()
assert(o.respond_to?(:method_x)) # getter
assert(o.respond_to?("method_x=".to_sym) # setter
```

Comment: the should_have_xxx methods _do_ depend on subclassing from ActiveRecord::Base. But the respond_to part of your answer was very concise. Accepting.

Comment: Shoulda (or test::unit, idk) has a convenience method: "assert_respond_to instance, sym"

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways, depending on how it's defined. If you defined it normally (somehow `def` or `define_method` in an `eval` or `class_eval`), then you can use `defined? obj.prop` to ensure that it responds to a reader (there's no equivalent for a writer). You can also use `obj.respond_to? :prop` for the reader, and `obj.respond_to? :prop=` for the writer.

If you're using `method_missing` to mimic a call for the property, then `obj.respond_to?` will only work if you redefined that as well (in which case you need to test it separately), and the only way to test your property is to try reading from it and writing to it, and asserting that it doesn't throw any exceptions.